# pd.read_csv for a "one-column" import: which sep avoids split as: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 4, saw 16"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, import

With a csv that has only one column, when running

```
pd.read_csv('/MYPATH/MYFILE.csv')
```

I get

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 4, saw 16
```

Or the long output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2158         except StopIteration:
   2159             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 4, saw 16
```

Obviously, it does not read the one-column csv as one column, as if the standard separator split the column. Therefore, I made the separator `None`, but running

```
pd.read_csv('/MYPATH/MYFILE.csv', sep=None)
```

throws

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _alert_malformed(self, msg, row_num)
   2996         """
   2997         if self.error_bad_lines:
-> 2998             raise ParserError(msg)
   2999         elif self.warn_bad_lines:
   3000             base = f"Skipping line {row_num}: "

ParserError: Expected 68 fields in line 26, saw 147
```

Which delimiter = separator that does not split the column at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a separator that never appears in your data. The separator is only to split the input into columns, not into rows, therefore we can do this:

```
pd.read_csv('/MYPATH/MYFILE.csv', sep="§§§")
```

or whatever character(s) that is/are *certainly* not in the csv. Then, the column will be read as one column, the separator will not detect any needed splits.

Without this, the standard separator is set to `sep=","` which obviously finds some commas in whatever column of the "one-column" csv.

Credits go to [Import CSV into pandas dataframe with list as column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255588/import-csv-into-pandas-dataframe-with-list-as-column).